# datetime conversion error in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column (Process Created Date) with date in the form of a string. When converting it to datetime format, am getting the below error.

data['Process Created Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Process Created Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

How can be converted to datetime (eg. 8/12/2017) ?

Comment: The error am getting is :

Comment: ValueError: time data datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 12, 0, 0) does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)

Comment: IIUC use `data['Process Created Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Process Created Date')`

Comment: When I run this, getting the below error.

Comment: TypeError: invalid string coercion to datetime